# Mock API when performing a WebTestCase and do $client->submitform() in Symfony 5

Tags: api, symfony

I have a Test which submits a form. This form usually results in performing doing a external API call. I want to mock that because I'm not interested in the API but in the action.

Whenever I call submitForm the client is still making an external call, but I don't want that.
The test also fails because the api expects a api key which the test does not have.

```
class SubscriptionControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSubscribe(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $userRepository = static::$container->get(UserRepository::class);
        $testUser       = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => UserFixtures::$testUser]);
        
        $clientMock = $this->createMock(ApiClient::class);
//replace the api with the mock one
        self::$container->set(ApiClient::class, $clientMock);

        $client->loginUser($testUser);
        $client->request('GET', '/subscription/new');
        $client->submitForm('btn-submit', [
            'subscribe[firstName]' => 'firstname',
            'subscribe[lastName]'  => 'lastname'
        ]);

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(201);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to mock the dependency in which your form submission code is calling that api. Are you sure you are doing this? Please show us that code to help you through! And what is the purpose of the first line `$client = static::createClient();` in your code?

Comment: @MAZux Yes, I am sure. I figured out what the problem was. A new kernel is being spung up everytime a request is done. So in this test I am doing 2 requests: A GET to /subscription/new and a submitform. The first request is giving me the proper Mock class however the submitform is giving me the ApiClient again. I changed my test to just do 1 request:

Comment: Tip: You can use Wirespec (https://wirespec.dev) to create mock APIs that provide a response at your own custom endpoint. It doesn't require the need for you to provide an API key. This makes it easier to test out your client code.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is described in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951344/3679577

TL:DR
2 requests are being done in my test. A GET and a submitForm (POST). First one uses the proper Mock, second request rebuilds the kernel and the mocks are gone.

My solution was to just use 1 request by submitting the form with a POST request. Using the CSRF token manager to generate a csrf token:

```
public function testSubscribe(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $userRepository = static::$container->get(UserRepository::class);
        $testUser       = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => UserFixtures::$testUser]);
        $csrfTokenGenerator = $client->getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager');

        $apiClient = $this->createMock(ApiClient::class);

        $client->getContainer()->set(ApiClient::class, $apiClient);

        $client->loginUser($testUser);
        $client->request('POST', '/subscription/new', [
            'subscribe' => [
                "firstName" => 'firstname',
                "lastName" => "lastname",
                "_token" => $csrfTokenGenerator->getToken('subscribe')->getValue()
            ]
        ]);

        $this->assertResponseRedirects('/subscription/thankyou');
    }
```